# Insert into table PLSQL with dynamic variable

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Well I have an dynamic variable

```
private_table_name VARCHAR2(100) := 'test';
```

`test` is the name of the table.

Now I want to insert into the table with this satatement.

```
INSERT INTO private_table_name VALUES (employee_rec.employee_id, concaternate_employee_name(employee_rec.employee_id), employee_rec.salary * 1.10);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is **dynamic SQL** you should use. For example:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE test
  2  (
  3     price   NUMBER
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> DECLARE
  2     private_table_name  VARCHAR2 (100) := 'test';
  3  BEGIN
  4     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE   'insert into '
  5                      || private_table_name
  6                      || ' (price) values (50)';
  7  END;
  8  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT * FROM test;

     PRICE
----------
        50

SQL>
```